# Heavy CRON Tasks

Tags: php, ajax, cron

I have to run a pretty heavy task on PHP once a week (script that curls to various locations (websites, API's), gathers, sorts data and inserts it into a db). The whole script takes about 10 to 15 mintues to run on my mac (localhost) - guessing it'll run a bit faster on a server. Nevertheless - I'm currently looping through with AJAX, so when each task is finished, next one is launched. Now I need to run it weekly, automatically. So I think I can't do it with AJAX Anymore.

Do I have to just set the php.ini to let a script run for 30 mintues or there is a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [maximum execution time](http://php.net/max-execution-time) of the PHP script is determined by the amount of time in which no output has been generated. So writing data into STDOUT (e.g. to a logfile) will keep the script running.

However, if you're running the script from command line, the max-execution-time will be defaulted to zero anyway and as already suggested, I'd start the script with a cronjob instead of an AJAX-Request or similar methods. I actually do that for most of my php-scripts performing administrative tasks like synchronizing data across several databases or similar purposes.

Comment: Okay, so no matter how long it takes for a PHP File to execute, running through a cron it won't run into any errors. Correct ?

Comment: correct - you still should check the php.ini-file, if your package maintainer did not put in a restriction by setting a limit (maximum execution time > 0). Also, remember that on linux-systems, there are different php.ini files for different environments, e.g. apache2 is different than the one for CLI (command line interface). And one more thing: with logfile, I specifically meant writing it to a pipe like `php myscript.php > /var/log/myscript.log`.

Answer (score 1):

php.ini has nothing to do with scheduling jobs. It's simply definining PHP's startup settings. What you want is a cron job, as your title says.

For OSX cron setup, see http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?s=&threadid=39005

Comment: Yeah, but I may get a PHP Runtime error because it's taking so long, or am I wrong about that ?

Comment: You shouldn't, I use something similar to stream data from twitter.  It runs for hours and I don't remember having to change any settings.

Comment: command-line PHP usually defaults to having no time-limit, and this is the environment the cron job would run in.

Comment: cron does not do web requests. you run the absolute path.